# Using isinstance() to remove integers from a json

Tags: python, json, isinstance

I'm coding in Python and working with a JSON file that has 2 columns of data; a key, and the number of times that key was found in the data I'm working with.  My goal is to remove all keys that are integers.

I've extracted the JSON as `test_map`, then used the `keys()` method which creates a dictionary(keys) of the keys.  I'm attempting to loop through keys using `isinstance` to identify each integer key in keys.  I have yet to get to the removal part, but I noticed that each key in keys are identified as strings, so `isinstance` isn't catching anything.

If anyone has any ideas as to how to code this to catch the int keys, then possibly to remove them, I would appreciate it.  I believe the solution involves casting but I can't figure it out.

```
keys=test_map.keys()
for key in keys:
    if isinstance(key,int):
        print(f"key: {key}")
```

I've edited to include a sample of the JSON file below.  I'm trying to remove the objects with integer keys.

```
    {
    "run": 121,
    "'988844333',": 4,    <remove
    "123": 27,            <remove
    "brown": 19,
    "face": 345,
    "21554,": 4,          <remove
    "gain": 4,
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "2 columns of data"? JSON isn't columnar.

Comment: Columns is incorrect.  It's a json that has a key and a frequency value associated with the key.

Comment: Nick: Those are called JSON "objects" and are unordered sets of name/value pairs (see [specification](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)). These get translated into Python dictionaries by the `json` module in the standard library.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a small sample of what's in the JSON file.

Comment: I added a sample of the JSON I'm working with.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The `.isdigit()` method  of string checks if the string is composed of just digits.
Here's the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=isdigit#str.isdigit)

We can use that to filter keys that are ints.

Here's the code:

```py
res = {k:v for k,v in test_map.items() if not k.isdigit()}
```

Comment: @martineau Updated post with comments per your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can try casting like this. But you need to write a try except in case the key is not convertible to int.

```
keys = [key for key in test_map]
for key in keys:
    try:
        a = int(key)
        del test_map[key]
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback.  When I run this I get a runtime error: dictionary changed size during iteration.  From what I've looked up, the issue is deleting from test_map while iterating.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, you are right, I have changed it to not refer to test_map keys but make copy of it.